# Checkbox label: "Refresh automatically" vs "Automatically refresh"

Tags: checkboxes, labels

I have a web page with a checkbox on it. The checkbox controls whether the list shown on the page is refreshed automatically: if checked, the list is refreshed every second; if unchecked, the list does not refresh.

I was wondering how best to label this checkbox.

> Refresh automatically

vs

> Automatically refresh

Either form is valid English, but I'm wondering whether the first is more idiomatic for buttons/checkboxes as it has the verb first. A quick straw poll in the office also showed a slight preference for this form.

I also toyed with

> Refresh every second

but the problem with that is that the refresh period may change.

**So, my question: should checkboxes generally be labelled verb-adverb or adverb-verb?**

Comment: This is probably a tech writing question, rather than a User Experience question. The grammar rules for writing are quite complex https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position

Comment: My recommendation is that when allowing a user to alter a state or functionality off an application in a binary way you might be better off using a switch/toggle UI pattern. I dedicate checkboxes to form inputs but this is up to you and your design system. As per wording, I recommend using, "Keep List Updated".

However my questions to you: Would your users want automatic reloads? Why would a user want a one time refresh button? Would your users not want automatic refresh option? Would your users not want a single time refresh button?

Answer (score 5):

I would lean toward "refresh automatically" as the most informative word for scanning is "refresh," unless the context includes several options about refreshing such as "refresh all." In the case of a cluster or chunk of options about refreshing, I would more likely front load the "automatically." I would also use "automatically refresh" if that is already a pattern throughout the interface, of course.